# Deviation from Linear response in metals and Ohm's law

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, electrical-resistance, material-science

In metals, Ohm's law is an example of a *linear response* i.e., $I\propto V$ where $I$ is the current (response) due to the applied voltage $V$ (external force). For metals, can we have a breakdown of linear response i.e., can there be a region where the current increases nonlinearly with the applied voltage when the voltage is sufficiently high?

Comment: would a superconductor (e.g. aluminum) be one example?

Comment: How about a light bulb filament, which shows nonlinear I-V behavior as a result of large changes in temperature with current? Or if you're requiring the temperature to be constant, then there may be practical problems with performing experiments at very high currents. There will also be unavoidable electromigration effects starting to kick in when the current density gets above $10^6 A/cm^2$ or so.

Comment: The nonlinearly, in your example, is due to the resistance becoming a function of temperature and not current. Your second point is interesting @SamuelWeir

Comment: Look up topics on the generalized Ohm's law.  In metals, typically the $\eta \mathbf{j}$ term dominates, thus why voltage is often linearly related to current.  I know that the Hall term becomes an issue (mostly for mechanical stress and unwanted extra heating) in very large pulsed current devices like the LHC, rail guns, and NIF.  If temperatures get high enough, I am guessing one could get effective pressure gradients built up in the wire/metal during the rise/fall of the current pulse.  In short, I am sure one could create a nonlinear response if one wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the other way around. Why would you expect any relation to be precisely linear? There would have to be some kind of symmetry to ensure that. There is no such symmetry, so the electric current-field relation (Ohm) is not exactly linear, the heat current-temperature gradient relation (Fourier) is not exactly linear, the stress-strain relation in fluids (Navier-Stokes) is not exactly linear ..

One may ask whether there are systems for which corrections to linearity are unusually large. In the case of fluids (the Navier-Stokes law) these are called non-Newtonian fluids, and the standard examples are cornstarch and ketchup. In the case of Ohm's law the examples are maybe less obvious. Recently, people have studied [unusual response](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/early/2016/02/10/science.aad0201) in narrow channels in graphene.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you can get a non linear response as an increase in current increases the temperature of a resistor which, in turn, increases resistance.

An example where current increases non linearly with applied voltage when is sufficiently high is the Metal Oxide Varistor (MOV). It is a voltage dependent resistor whose electrical resistance varies with applied voltage. At low voltages its current is very small (considered leakage). At sufficiently high voltage it’s current increases dramatically non- linearly and the voltage across it drops. It behaves similarly to a diode but has the same behavior for both directions of current flow. The device is connected across the line and is intended to suppress transient overvoltages thus protecting down stream equipment.